# XPath issue HTML Parsing

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Container Title | foldr.us</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="base.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>

        <!-- menu scripts  -->

        <!-- cycle scripts  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <!-- cycle scripts  -->

        <!-- newsticker scripts  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <!-- newsticker scripts  -->

        <!-- twitter scripts  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweetable.js"></script>
        <!-- twitter scripts  -->

        <!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
        <script src="js/DD_belatedPNG.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>  DD_belatedPNG.fix('.*'); </script>
        <![endif]-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://wmonkey.org/media/likefoldr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="home">
        <div class="container_12 main_page">
            <div class="grid_3">
                <div class="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/blank.gif" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_9">
                <div class="menu_bg">
                    <ul class="sf-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.relink.us/earnmoney.php" target="_blank">Earn money</a></li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="/foldr.php?id=82dca8a8506023bfc4ac08938&hl=de"><img src="images/de.gif" alt="de" />&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="/foldr.php?id=82dca8a8506023bfc4ac08938&hl=en"><img src="images/us.gif" alt="us" />&nbsp;</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--Middle content Section starts-->
        <div class="container_12 mid_bg_home">
            <div class="subpage"> 
                <h2>Container Title</h2>
                <div class="subpage_text">
                    <strong>Foldr ID</strong><br />82dca8a8506023bfc4ac08938                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mid_content">


<center>

<!--/* propellerads */-->

<iframe id='52811b97a4d79' name='52811b97a4d79' src='http://ad.propellerads.com/afr.php?zoneid=10877' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90'><a href='http://ad.propellerads.com/ck.php?n=52811b97a4d79' target='_blank'><img src='http://ad.propellerads.com/avw.php?zoneid=&n=52811b97a4d79' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
<!--/* propellerads */-->

                <h2 style="text-align:center;">W&auml;hlen Sie ihren bevorzugten Mirror.</h2>               <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>                        <td>
                            <div class="iconbox"> 
                                <h4>Container Title</h4>
                                <a href="http://relink.us/view.php?id=ad3a0748c3ccf64eb74fef9c11d3c6" name="Relink.us" target="_blank"><img src="images/hoster/ul.to.png" alt="ul.to" /></a>
                                <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Hoster: </strong>ul.to</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                                            <td>
                            <div class="iconbox last"> 
                                <h4>Container Title</h4>
                                <a href="http://relink.us/view.php?id=1f2d3abddeea67f98d83b83404447b" name="Relink.us" target="_blank"><img src="images/hoster/share-online.biz.png" alt="share-online.biz" /></a>
                                <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Hoster: </strong>share-online.biz</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr>                       <td>
                            <div class="iconbox"> 
                                <h4>Container Title</h4>
                                <a href="http://relink.us/view.php?id=79abcd910faaad8e7c61ac1a722b4d" name="Relink.us" target="_blank"><img src="images/hoster/zippyshare.com.png" alt="zippyshare.com" /></a>
                                <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Hoster: </strong>zippyshare.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                                            <td>
                            <div class="iconbox last"> 
                                <h3>Advertisement</h3>
                                <iframe id='a641a235' name='a641a235' src='http://delivery.adtwothree.com/afr.php?zoneid=11&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='250' height='250'><a href='http://delivery.adtwothree.com/ck.php?n=a68edb28&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://delivery.adtwothree.com/avw.php?zoneid=11&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a68edb28' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>                         </div>
                        </td>
                                </tr>               </table>
            </div>
            <!--Middle content Section ends-->
        </div>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://onclickads.net/apu.php?zoneid=10875'></script>   
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <!--Footer content Section starts-->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="grid_6 footer_left">
                    <span class="logo_small">&nbsp;</span>
                    <p>&copy; 2010-2014 <a href="">www.foldr.us</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6 footer_right">
                    <h3>Feedback</h3>
                    <p>Anregung, Kritik, Vorschl&auml;ge?!</p>
                    <strong>Email :</strong> <a href="mailto:yxc">support@relink.us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--Footer content Section ends-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-8662050-13']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My XPath Query is this: `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a/@href` and I use this PHP code for parsing it. But it prints out NULL not the link which I want. Where's my mistake?

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOM->loadHTML($fold); //$fold is the html document.

$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$items = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a/@href");

echo $items->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `tbody` in your source.

You can skip it either removing the `tbody` step from your XPath expression or replacing it with a `descendant` (`//`) location step (which will allow it, or any tag between `table` and `tr` in case it is defined in the source):

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/center/table//tr[1]/td[1]/div/a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a better chance of surviving a change in the source html if you look for specific clues to get to the value in question, rather than an exact path from the top of the document.

In your case I suggest this xpath:

```
//a[img/@alt = 'ul.to']/@href
```

What it means is look for all `<a>` tags (which contain an `<img>` tag that has attribute alt='ul.to'), then get the href of the `<a>` tags.